# Why doesn't ls -lu show correct access time?

Tags: ext4, ls

Why isn't "ls -lu" showing the access time, instead of the modification time on an ext4 file system?

```
$ date
Mon Jan  9 12:49:31 EST 2017
$ ls -lu ~/.bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 scott scott 4326 Jan  8 18:16 /home/scott/.bashrc
$ wc ~/.bashrc
 139  574 4326 /home/scott/.bashrc
$ ls -lu ~/.bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 scott scott 4326 Jan  8 18:16 /home/scott/.bashrc
$ df .
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      447651680 154618396 270270840  37% /
$ mount | grep sda1
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

Comment: Read up on "relatime" It does NOT do what you believe it to do. Here is a reference: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8842/10017

Comment: I didn't know there was any such thing as relatime until I read your comment, to be honest. So what it amounts to is that atime is usually disabled at the file system level and replaced with either relatime, which updates once a day, or noatime, which doesn't update at all, for performance reasons?  If that's the case, then I'd think adding that to the documentation for ls would be highly desirable.

Comment: But is is documented in the mount option ;-)

Comment: Yes, but having to intuit that you should ignore the command documentation, and have to guess that the functionality described has been intentionally disabled, and then to have to guess further which documentation to hunt for in order to find out whether or why isn't very reasonable.